# How do I extract significant text content from a LaTeX document

Tags: latex, plagiarism-detection

I need to extract **text-only** content from my thesis document written in LaTeX for an automated anti-plagiarism check. I know only about the "draft" option and it's not enough.

I am supposed to omit:

- images,
- tables and other figures,
- equations,
- captions and footnotes.

It'd also be nice to remove all the references. The output should be a plain (UTF-8 encoded) text file.

Is there any straightforward way to do this?
I don't really fancy copying it manually page-by-page.

Comment: Let me guess - your institution's anti-plagiarism software only works on MSWord documents and plain text files?

Comment: Good guess Spacedman, but only plain text. I guess that's reasonable since it's not so easy to automate on their end.

Comment: You might get more answers at the [TeX SE site](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the comment package (or one of a dozen of alternatives) to turn equation, figure, table etc. into commenting environments and \renewcommand\footnote[1]{} to remove footnotes. \pagestyle{empty} should remove page headings etc., so running pdftotext on the result should come close ot what you want.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm going to try this. I don't really understand the bit about comment package. Does it comment out all the environments automatically or do I have to specify some env list to some command?

Comment: @odiroot: one example, adapted from the `verbatim` package, would look like this:
`\usepackage{verbatim}\let\equation=\comment\let\endequation=\endcomment`
should suppress all your equation environments. So yes, you'll have a bit of typing doing this for equation, align, ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes: [untex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/untex), a simple C script. You can also look at [detex](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/trinkle/detex/).

Comment: I tried detex, it does help but still produces a lot of cruft. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a document converter like [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), or convert the output PDF to plain text with something like [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com).

Answer (score 1):

Usually you want some LaTeX processing done on the text, say you have

> \newcommand*{\SO}{StackOverflow\index{StackOverflow}\xspace}
>
> ...
>
> I spend a lot of time on \SO, blah
>   blah ....

Just filtering out the text paragraph here will not give a text like the intended result when it contains any macros.

Therefore trying to extract things directly from the *.tex file usually will leave much to be wanted from the result. It is typically therefore better to work on output from latex processing. I would recommend to convert latex to html and then from html to text. You will probably need some manual clean-up, but I think it should be relatively close.

Comment: Thanks for the html->txt tip. 

I'm currently replacing footnotes and caption with empty string using `renewcommand`. But I still haven't figured out how to do the same with `tabular(x)` since it has begin- and endtags.

Answer (score 1):

While detex has been mentioned, however there is another project, aimed at improving it. It is called [opendetex](http://code.google.com/p/opendetex/), give it a look!